# ReactJS server side rendering with hot reloading (webpack-dev-server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to build my first server side rendering with ReactJS. I've based my code from [this Redux tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html)

The application is working fine when running `npm start` (`webpack && node server.js`).

I want to use hot reloading to be able to do an application fast debugging on dev environment. So I've added the `start` option on my npm configuration (`webpack-dev-server --inline --hot`). Notice that I don't have a index.html file as react-router is choosing the proper JSX file to load.

npm start opens my public folder and show files, but does no start my application. Normally I would click on a index.html file, but I have none.

I can't understand what's going on and don't know how to solve. Help appreciated.

**package.json:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
    "dev": "webpack && node server.js"
  },
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './client.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**server.js**

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
});

var express = require('express');
var config = require('config');
var app = express();

var serverConfig = config.get('serverConfig');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(require('./routes/index.jsx'));

app.listen(serverConfig.port, function () {
    console.log('FactoryWays server running on port ' + serverConfig.port);
    console.log('Press CTRL-C to stop the server.');
});
```

**client.js**

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');
var routes = require('./routes/routes.jsx');
var Redux = require('redux');
var Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;

function reducer(state) { return state; }

var store = Redux.createStore(reducer, window.PROPS);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {routes}
    </Provider>, document
);
```

**routes/index.jsx:**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Redux = require('redux');
var Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;

function reducer(state) { return state; }

router.get('*', function(request, response) {
    var initialState = { title: 'Universal React' };
    var store = Redux.createStore(reducer, initialState);

    ReactRouter.match({
        routes: require('./routes.jsx'),
        location: request.url
    }, function(error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        if (renderProps) {
            var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <ReactRouter.RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
            );
            response.send(html);
        } else {
            response.status(404).send('Not Found');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/routes.jsx:**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

module.exports = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={require('../views/Layout.jsx')}>
            <IndexRoute component={require('../views/Index.jsx')} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

**views/Layout.jsx:**

```
var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var connect = require('react-redux').connect;

var Layout = React.createClass({
    _handleClick: function() {
        alert();
    },
    render: function() {
        var custom = this.props.custom;
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>{custom.title}</title>
                    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>{custom.title}</h1>
                    <p>Isn't server-side rendering remarkable?</p>
                    <button onClick={this._handleClick}>Click Me</button>
                    {this.props.children}
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: 'window.PROPS=' + JSON.stringify(custom)
                    }} />
                    <script src='/bundle.js' />
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
});

var wrapper = connect(
    function(state) {
        return { custom: state };
    }
);

module.exports = wrapper(Layout);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice that I don't have a index.html file as react-router is choosing the proper JSX file to load

You still need one if you're running `webpack-dev-server`.

Webpack is used to bundle JavaScript together. That's it. In your case (based on your `webpack.config.js` file), it's outputting a `bundle.js` file in your `public` directory.

Webpack Dev Server is a simple static file server to aid development. It doesn't know anything about your server configuration in `server.js`.

Your two commands in your package.json require different setups:

**`npm start`**

`npm start` runs `webpack-dev-server`. By default, [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) will serve the contents of your current directory, so you'll need to put your an `index.html` in the root directory of your project. The contents of `index.html` are simple: just boilerplate HTML that includes a `script` tag linking to your `bundle.js` file.

**`npm dev`**

When you're running `npm dev` however, you're rolling your own server, defined in `server.js`. In that case it's configured to generate and serve an `index.html` (as well as all the other static files you need) for you.

If you want to do hot-reloading *and* run your own server, you can add [webpack-dev-middleware](http://madole.github.io/blog/2015/08/26/setting-up-webpack-dev-middleware-in-your-express-application/) to your Express server.

Comment: Thanks for the post @bejado. Some questions: 1. I understand my index.html content shall be equal to that content in `views/Layout.jsx`. I can then create a index.html file from that content and serve it both in `dev` and in `start`. Please elaborate  2. My final goal is to run my server AND do hot-reloading. So, I shall change webpack-dev-server to webpack-dev-middleware ? Shall I do that in both production and development (where I don't need it) ? How can I configure for both conditions ? Please elaborate both conditions if you can.

Comment: Also, I've seen webpack-hot-middleware. What is this related to ?